# C Reading Negative Integers From Text File

Tags: c

I am working on a project. there is a .txt file that includes negative integers like this

```
0 -1 0
-1 20 -1
0 -1 0
```

My problem is I couldn't read negative numbers. What is your suggestions for this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE *fptr;
    char letter;
    fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if(fptr == NULL){
        printf("Please provide an argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ( ( letter = fgetc(fptr) ) != EOF ) {
        printf("%c",letter);
    }

    printf("\n");


    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you reading the positive ones?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of what you have tried.

Comment: I am edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't read any numbers, so I'm not sure what it has to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to read the lines from the file and then parse your numbers.
getline reads a line from your file and strtok then gives you a string until the specified delimeter (space in your case). Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    FILE * fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t lineSize = 0;

    if(fptr == NULL){
        printf("Please provide an argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(getline(&line, &lineSize, fptr) != -1) {

        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;

        printf("%s\n", line);

        char * token = strtok(line, " ");

        printf("%s\n", token);

        while((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {

            printf("%s\n", token);
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```